# How to set text color of a radio button when a button is pressed in Android?

Tags: java, android, loops, if-statement, onclicklistener

I have 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. Every radio button represents an answer to a question. I want when someone press the button, if the correct answer is checked, to set the color of the that text in green. With this code, when i press the button, nothing happens. Any ideas?
Here is my code:

```
boolean isChecked;
int CorrectAnswer;
RadioButton checkedRadioButton;

    answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = ((RadioButton) v);
        int CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());
        isChecked = true;
        if (isChecked) {
            if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked() & CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                score++;
                isChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
                radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);
                    if (CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                        checkedRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to interface with the selected radiobutton would be not to take V but to just straight get the ID from the RadioGroup. You would do something like this:

```
int selectedId = yourRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
selected = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
selected.setTextColor(Color.Green);
```

Once you have the selected radio button as referenced by selected above you can do whatever you want even from your other listener. Also the only place you are changing the text color is in the finishButton listener. Are you trying to change the color when you click the right RadioButton? You are incrementing th score etc in your other listener so why not set the color there instead of in the finishButton(); Now you can still set this there just make sure you are properly selecting the radio button.

**EDIT**

Alright here is a very simple example of what I was referring to. Notice I created a temporary global variable that will hold the selected device. Now this isn't in a nested for loop but the principle is 100% the same.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn, btn2;
RadioGroup radioButtonGroup;
RadioButton selected;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    radioButtonGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rad);
    boolean isValid = false;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        RadioButton rad;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(selected != null) {
                selected.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            }
            int selectedId = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            selected = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            selected.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(selected != null) {
                selected.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            }
            int selectedId = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            selected = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            selected.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**And here is how it looks**

[image]

and on click of two

[image]

Comment: As i see, the radio button declaration is inside of the `onclicklistener`. If i move `RadioButton checkedRadioButton;` inside the first `OnClickListener` i can't see `checkedRadioButton` in the second `OnClickListener`.  What can i do?

Comment: I declaread `RadioButton selected;` as global. In the `OnClickListener` i added the 3 lines you wrote but when i click the button, i get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference`.
No, i don't want to change the color when someone clicks on the right button. I want only when someone press the `finishButton();`.

Comment: Once again can you post what you have haha hardest time visualizing it. The error you got is because it isn't seeing the assignment of the variable so in turn it is null.

Comment: Yes move the declaration of RadioButton checkedRadioButton outside of the onclick. Still assign it there just move the declaration outside so that your other listener still has access :) driving home but if you still don't get it when I get home I can post code

Comment: If i move the declaration of RadioButton checkedRadioButton outside of the onclick, i need to move also the `int checkedRadioButtonId = radioGroup[i].getCheckedRadioButtonId();` which i cannot do that, because i need the `radioGroup[i]` to be in the loop. When you get home, please write me some code. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the lines. It works in your example because you have the radio buttons and the radio group added manually. I did it dynamically. For the radio group, you can use `findViewById(R.id.rad);` but how can i do that? How can i `findViewById` the radiogroup? Look at my [code](http://gogo.ro/21.png).

Comment: Please take a look at my updated [code](http://gogo.ro/22.png) but unfortunately i have the same error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94715/discussion-between-jordan-seanor-and-alex-m).